# How can I shorten timeout times using restfb request?

Tags: java, httprequest, restfb

I am using FacebookClient class and publish function when requesting. I want to shorten timeout times. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extend the `DefaultWebRequstor` class and override the `customizeConnection` method. There you can modify the `connection` object and set your custom timeout.

```
@Override
protected void customizeConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) {
  connection.setReadTimeout(YOUR_VALUE_IN_MS);
}
```

Afterwards you have to use this custom web requestor in the constructor of the DefaultFacebookClient class.

```
FacebookClient client = 
  new DefaultFacebookClient(ACCESS_TOKEN, 
                         new CustomWebRequestor(), // your requestor
                         new DefaultJsonMapper(), 
                         Version.LATEST);
```

And you're done. 
With this method you can modify the connection even further.